# how save a file in Python whose name has slashes in it

Tags: python, string

I am looping through a series of names in a tuple and I want to save the output during each loop using the tuple data as the filename. However the names have slashes in them.

```
layers = ['conv1/7x7_s2','pool1/3x3_s2']
for idx,layer in enumerate(layers):
    result=deepdream(net, img, end=layer)
    imag = PIL.Image.fromarray(result,'RGB')
    imag.save('files/'+str(layer)+'.png')
```

result contains a numpy array
imag is the image
layer is what i want the filename to be

However, the slash is being interpreted as a directory delimiter
Is there any way to save the image as
conv1/7x7_s2.png

or should I just convert the slash to a dash?

Comment: From my understanding there are a handful of characters that are specifically used for the operating system and can never be used in names. the slash is one of them. I would recommend changing it to a dash or another character.

Comment: If you are trying to save files in windows with forward slashes in name, you can't do it. [Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file) this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, there are some convoluted ways of keeping the "slash," but they probably aren't worth it (i.e. using a unicode division slash).

```
layers = ['conv1/7x7_s2','pool1/3x3_s2']
for idx, layer in enumerate(layers):
    print(layer.replace('/', '_'))
    # or maybe this might work?
    # print(layer.replace('/', u"\u2215"))
```

Comment: sorry I should have been clearer - i am using linux. but yes i am trying to 'simulate' the slash character in the filename so i will probably use a unicode character that looks to humans like a slash but really is not. thanks to eric for the idea.

Comment: Unless the goal is to confuse the user (it could be), it's generally not a good idea to use a character that looks like another character - it will only cause the user to type things with unexpected results. For example, if you have a folder called `files/docs` (with a 'fake' slash) and someone runs `rm -f files/docs/*`, expecting to remove the files in that folder, they will have wiped all the files in the `docs` folder in the `files` folder instead.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. I guess I should've expanded on the reasons doing something like this "probably [isn't] worth it."

Answer (score 4):

None of these characters can be used in filenames (at least not on a Windows file system): `\`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>` and `|`. They all have specific alternate meanings.

There is also no escape character or another way around it - you will simply need to omit or replace these characters in file names.

Answer (score 0):

As the directory structure is defined you **can't**. As linux systems will parse the / as a component of the directory tree. You should simply change the slash to dash or underscores.